# Passing around Services in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection

I really like the idea of dependency injection. I'm having trouble applying the concept though because most examples I see are for ASP.NET MVC.

Here's what I got: WPF -> Services -> Repository. Services get repositories injected and my view models (well at least one, anyway) gets the services injected.

And then in my WPF App.xaml I'm overriding the OnStartup method. This is where I am creating Ninject and resolving my first view.

I get lost when it comes to multiple views. For example, say I injected ServiceA and ServiceB into my first view model (in App.xaml). Let's say somewhere down the line I want ServiceC in another view model's constructor, how would I get that to inject into the constructor?

In code speak, it's like this:

```
public class ViewModel1
{
    private readonly IServiceA serviceA;
    private readonly IServiceB serviceB;

    public ViewModel1(IServiceA serviceA, IServiceB serviceB)
    {
        this.serviceA = serviceA;
        this.serviceB = serviceB;
    }

    public void OpenASettingsWindow()
    {
        // How do I resolve this view?
        var window = new View(new ViewModel2(new ServiceC()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a factory which creates instances of the `View`. Factory constructor will have `ServiceC` parameter. Then you need to inject the factory to the `ViewModel1`.
The code below is based on your code. Ideally, `ViewModel1` does not need to know anything about the `View` class - it should deal with more abstract interfaces like `IWhateverWindow` which can can have methods like `Show`.

```
public class ViewFactory
{
    private ServiceC _serviceC;

    public VewFactory(ServiceC serviceC)
    {
        _serviceC = serviceC;
    }

    public View CreateView()
    {
        return new View(new ViewModel(_serviceC));
    }
}

public class ViewModel1
{
    private readonly IServiceA serviceA;
    private readonly IServiceB serviceB;
    private ViewFactory _viewFactory;

    public ViewModel1(IServiceA serviceA, IServiceB serviceB, ViewFactory viewFactory)
    {
        this.serviceA = serviceA;
        this.serviceB = serviceB;
        _viewFactory = viewFactory;
    }

    public void OpenASettingsWindow()
    {
        // How do I resolve this view?
        var window = _viewFactory.CreateView();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating View directly in ViewModel's code is a primary violation of MVVM principles. ViewModels should be unaware of Views. There are many ways to open window in MVVM fashion. You can see some of these in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242817/resolving-wpf-windows-in-structure-map/20593613#20593613).